# VBA (RFC) SAP export to excel

Tags: excel, vba, export, saprfc

I am writing a VB application for connecting to a SAP system (using RFC).
Everything works fine and I do get a connection and the data as well.

Nevertheless the code for saving the accessed data and writing it to a excel file is really slow.

After the connection I call `RFC_READ_TABLE`, which returns with a result in <5 secs, which is perfect. Writing to excel (cell by cell) is pretty slow.

Is there any way to 'export' the whole `tblData` to Excel and not being dependent on writing cell by cell?

Thanks in advance!

```
If RFC_READ_TABLE.Call = True Then
    MsgBox tblData.RowCount
    If tblData.RowCount > 0 Then
    
        ' Write table header
        For j = 1 To Size
            Cells(1, j).Value = ColumnNames(j)
        Next j
        
        Size = UBound(ColumnNames, 1) - LBound(ColumnNames, 1) + 1
    
        For i = 1 To tblData.RowCount
            DoEvents
            Textzeile = tblData(i, "WA")

            For j = 1 To Size
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = LTrim(RTrim(getPieceOfTextzeile(Textzeile)))
            Next j

       Next
    Else
       MsgBox "No entries found in system " & SYSID, vbInformation
    End If
    
Else
   MsgBox "ERROR CALLING SAP REMOTE FUNCTION CALL"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Arrays: Faster Than Ranges

If the data was ready (need not to be processed) something like this could be a solution:

```
Sub Sap()

    Const cStrStart As String = "A1" 'First cell of the resulting data

    Dim tbldata
    Dim arrSap As Variant 'Will become a one-based two dimensional array
    Dim oRng As Range

        arrSap = tbldata 'Data is in the array.

        'Calculate the range: Must be the same size as arrSap
        Set oRng = Range(Cells(Range(cStrStart).Row, UBound(arrSap)), _
            Cells(Range(cStrStart)).Column, UBound(arrSap, 2))

        oRng = arrSap 'Paste array into range.

End Sub
```

Since you need to process your data from tbldata do what you do not to the range, but to an array which should be much faster:

```
Sub Sap()

    Const cStrStart As String = "A1" 'First cell of the resulting data

    Dim arrSap() As Variant
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim Size As Integer

    If RFC_READ_TABLE.Call = True Then
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        MsgBox tbldata.RowCount
        If tbldata.RowCount > 0 Then
            Size = UBound(ColumnNames, 1) - LBound(ColumnNames, 1) + 1
            ReDim arrSap(1 To tbldata.RowCount + 1, 1 To Size) '+ 1 for header
            ' Write table header
            For j = 1 To Size
                arrSap(1, j).Value = ColumnNames(j)
            Next j
            ' Write data
            For i = 1 + 1 To tbldata.RowCount + 1 '+ 1 for header
                DoEvents
                '- 1 due to header, don't know what "WA" is
                Textzeile = tbldata(i - 1, "WA")
                For j = 1 To Size
                    arrSap(i, j) = _
                        LTrim(RTrim(getPieceOfTextzeile(Textzeile)))
                Next j
            Next
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Calculate the range: Must be the same size as arrSap
            Set oRng = Range(Cells(Range(cStrStart).Row, Range(cStrStart).Column), _
                Cells(UBound(arrSap) + Range(cStrStart).Row -1, _
                UBound(arrSap, 2) + Range(cStrStart).Column -1))
            oRng = arrSap
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Else
            MsgBox "No entries found in system " & SYSID, vbInformation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "ERROR CALLING SAP REMOTE FUNCTION CALL"
    End If

End Sub
```

Now adjust the cStrStart, check the rest of the code and you're good to go.
I haven't created a working example so I edited this code a few times. Check it carefully not to lose data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I took your code as an inspiration.
Dumping the Cell of the tblData
    tbldata.Cell(i, 1)
and splitting at the @ sign (which is returned by the sap system)
    tmp = Split(input_text, "@")
I think my getPieceOfTextzeile function, which was called on every cell was slowing everything down.

Comment: Nice going. Glad I could help and thanks for the reward. Respect.